# How to update user app ID and password with onelogin API

Tags: onelogin

Trying to automate the manual process of updating a user's app id and password for One Login. When the user gets created, we have to manually go to user > applications > select app > update ID and password. 
Is there API I could use to update the user's app ID and password? I could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

There's two APIs to set a user's password:
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/set-password-in-cleartext
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/set-password-using-sha-256

Depending on where your user is mastered, you might have to adhere to password complexity rules not maintained in Onelogin, so prepare for that in your code.

Why would you change the value set for the user's Subject ( NameID ) in the app ? Is your data inconsistent so you can't set a rule for that in the standard app configuration ? 
The new app API might do that for you, but if you're needing to do that process on a consistent basis, then you should be doing some house keeping in your data source.
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/apps/update-app

Comment: I want to edit users "APP" password under User > Applications not just user's password for onelogin. 
There are apps that are not SAML compatible which needs to be manually entered every time we have new user which I am trying to automate using API but seems like there is none.